# Installing font libraries in google colab

Tags: python, python-3.7, google-colaboratory

I am executing an image classification program in google colab and I need to write some text on the image. But it is showing the following error. I don't know how to install these font libraries.
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://buomsoo-kim.github.io/colab/2018/04/27/Using-External-fonts-in-colab.md/) helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked for me.